# Logistic function with different asymptotic slopes

Tags: sigmoid-curve

The asymptotic slope of both sides of a logistic/sigmoid function is zero. What would be the equation of a logistic function with a different asymptotic slope on each side? I'm trying to model data with that behavior.

---

I'm trying to model experimental data into one single function. The data looks like that:
[image: Data points]

At low x, data slope is zero, at high x, slope is different from 0. Note that the transition from sigmoid to linear is smooth.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I don't think that would be considered a "logistic" function anymore. Please provide some data or a graph that illustrates what you are trying to model. Then you might get some useful suggestions for how to proceed.

Comment: Add any asymptotic trend you like to the logistic.  Any piecewise linear function with a finite number of breaks would do the trick, for instance. The generality of this solution demonstrates you need to supply more information about your model.